# I want to return the start date and finish date of every iteration

Tags: azure-devops

Visual studio team services

[[image: ![]I would like to return the sprint starts with the corresponding sprint end dates any idea how i can get the correct data out of the platform]

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Form the screen shot you list, the dates are for work items not iterations. Such as the Closed date as below is the date when the work item state changed to `Closed`.

[image]

To get start data and finish date for each iteration, you should use the [**REST API to list iterations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/iterations/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) instead of using queries.

The format of the REST API to get each iteration as below:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=4.1
```

Then you can get each iteration's start date and finish date from response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I only get this response back from the API

Answer (score 0):

[![Iam getting visual studio team services sign in popup[1]][1]

because of that nothing works anymore